# Ansible Playbook: Exchange variable between playbooks

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I need an idea how can I use output variable of one Playbook in another playbook. they both are called using include statement

Detailed Explanation:

I have one master playbook and two child playbooks. I want to use output variable of child1 playbook as in child2 playbook

I have tried to register but no luck

### Main.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
- name: executing child1 playbook
  include: child1.yaml
- name:  executing child2 playbook
  include: child2.yaml
```

### child1.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
- name: print to stdout
  command: echo "hello"
  register: test1
```

### child2.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
- name: print to stdout
  command: echo '{{ test }}'
  register: test2
```

I want variable test1 of playbook child1 out so that I can use in child2 playbook

Comment: I don't see any attempts to use `test1` variable.

Comment: use include in your test2 playbook.

Comment: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/YAML+inherit+and+include#YAMLinheritandinclude-YAMLinclude